# Electron app using electron-updater with s3 causes access denied error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, electron, electron-builder

I am building an electron app and trying to implement the auto-update feature where it looks in an amazon s3 bucket for the latest version.
However, I am getting the following error when I run the app.

```
16:10:20.940 > App starting...
16:10:25.291 > isDev =  false
16:10:25.341 > isElectron =  true
(electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.  For more information please check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397
16:10:27.024 > setting server
16:10:27.334 > creating electron window...
16:10:27.372 > Checking for update
16:10:27.380 > Checking for update...
16:10:27.390 > Checking for update...
16:10:31.295 > Error: HttpError: 403 Forbidden
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CCAC73A34CC51E4F</RequestId><HostId>UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=</HostId></Error>"
Headers: {
  "x-amz-request-id": "CCAC73A34CC51E4F",
  "x-amz-id-2": "UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Mar 2020 05:10:30 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3"
}
    at createHttpError (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:84:10)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:200:18)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
16:10:31.312 > Error in auto-updaterHttpError: 403 Forbidden
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CCAC73A34CC51E4F</RequestId><HostId>UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=</HostId></Error>"
Headers: {
  "x-amz-request-id": "CCAC73A34CC51E4F",
  "x-amz-id-2": "UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Mar 2020 05:10:30 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3"
}
16:10:31.335 > Error in auto-updater. HttpError: 403 Forbidden
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CCAC73A34CC51E4F</RequestId><HostId>UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=</HostId></Error>"
Headers: {
  "x-amz-request-id": "CCAC73A34CC51E4F",
  "x-amz-id-2": "UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Mar 2020 05:10:30 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3"
}
(node:46716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: 403 Forbidden
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CCAC73A34CC51E4F</RequestId><HostId>UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=</HostId></Error>"
Headers: {
  "x-amz-request-id": "CCAC73A34CC51E4F",
  "x-amz-id-2": "UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Mar 2020 05:10:30 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3"
}
    at createHttpError (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:84:10)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:200:18)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:46716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: 403 Forbidden
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CCAC73A34CC51E4F</RequestId><HostId>UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=</HostId></Error>"
Headers: {
  "x-amz-request-id": "CCAC73A34CC51E4F",
  "x-amz-id-2": "UV6SzCBOwvKCyG7LHLS3gioVz5vad+YKbaaF1oinui3a272DUf/7TDKoywjzA4YP+3jLYz3i70Q=",
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Mar 2020 05:10:30 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3"
}
    at createHttpError (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:84:10)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\Documents\myelectronapp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:200:18)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:46716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:46716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:46716) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:46716) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I think it has to do with my aws tokens not being used?
They are in my .env file but not sure how the electron-builder is retrieving this

.env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<exampleKeyId>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<exampleAccessKey>
```

package.json - build

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.myname.electron-app",
    "productName": "myElectronApp",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 ${author}",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities"
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "s3",
      "bucket": "mybucketname"
    }
}
```

main electron.js file

```
const { ipcMain, app, BrowserWindow, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const os = require('os');
const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');
const isElectron = require('is-electron');
const log = require('electron-log');

//Load Dev only modules
// if(isDev) {
//   require('electron-reload');
//   require('dotenv').load();
// }

let mainWindow;
let serverWindow;

autoUpdater.logger = log;
autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info';
log.info('App starting...');
log.info('isDev = ', isDev);
log.info('isElectron = ', isElectron());

function createWindow() {
  log.info('creating electron window...');
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1500, 
      height: 680,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? `http://localhost:3000/` : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
  if (isDev) {
    //BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('<location to your react chrome extension>');
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    if (isElectron()) {
      //Install Dev Tools using just Electron
      BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(
        path.join(os.homedir(), '/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/2.17.0_0')
      )

      BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension(
        path.join(os.homedir(), '/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/4.4.0_0')
      )
    }
  }
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

function startExpress() {
  log.info('setting server');
  //Create the server window.
  serverWindow = new BrowserWindow(
    {
      width: 1500, 
      height: 680,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
      }
    }
    // :
    // {
    //   show: false
    // }
  );

  // if(isDev) { serverWindow.webContents.openDevTools(); }

  //console.log('server path', `file://${path.join(__dirname, '\\server\\server.html')}`);
  serverWindow.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '\\server\\server.html')}`)
}

app.on('ready', () => {     
  startExpress();
  createWindow();
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

ipcMain.on('catch-on-main', (event, args) => {
  //Do stuff
})

ipcMain.on('get-app-version', (event) => {
  console.log('appversion=', app.getVersion());
  mainWindow.webContents.send('set-app-version', app.getVersion());
});

ipcMain.on('restart-app', () => {
  console.log('restarting the app...');
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});

ipcMain.on('server-running', () => {
  console.log('ipcMain channel entered server-running');
  mainWindow.webContents.send('relay-server-running');
})

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
  log.info('Checking for update...');
  sendStatusToWindow('Checking for update...');
})
autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  log.info('Update available');
  sendStatusToWindow('Update available.');
})
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  log.info('Update not available.');
  sendStatusToWindow('Update not available.');
})
autoUpdater.on('download-update', () => {
  log.info('downloading update...');
  sendStatusToWindow('download-update.');
});
autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  log.info('Error in auto-updater' + err);
  sendStatusToWindow('Error in auto-updater. ' + err);
})
autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
  let log_message = "Download speed: " + progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
  log_message = log_message + ' - Downloaded ' + progressObj.percent + '%';
  log_message = log_message + ' (' + progressObj.transferred + "/" + progressObj.total + ')';
  log.info(log_message);
  sendStatusToWindow(log_message);
})
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  log.info('Update downloaded.');
  sendStatusToWindow('Update downloaded');
});

function sendStatusToWindow(text) {
  log.info(text);
  mainWindow.webContents.send('message', text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason was that I wasn't including my .env file which had the secret keys in my build.

Comment: how did you add .env file in the build.   Can you pls link me any document which explains this?  Thanks!